# How can i view only my sheetname on jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Hi everyone i'm new in java, i've just created a program for viewing excel file, and it working perfectly, but now i wanted to create a jsp page, where i have a table, and in this table i want to view the excel file sheetname, i don't know where to start, here is my code for viewing the excel content:

```
public class ReadInvoices {

private static final String NAME = "C:\\Users\\........\\excelfile.xlsx";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(NAME));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        Iterator<Sheet> sheets = workbook.sheetIterator();
        while(sheets.hasNext()) {
            Sheet sh = sheets.next();
            System.out.println("Sheet name is "+sh.getSheetName()); //HERE IS WHEN I PRINT THE SHEET NAME ON CONSOLE, THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO VIEW ON MY JSP PAGE.

            System.out.println("---------");
            Iterator<Row> iterator = sh.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

                    System.out.print(cellValue+"\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        workbook.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

And here is my jsp page for now, with the table only.

```
    <html lang="it-it" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

   <head>   
     </head>
     <body>

    <table class="center">
    <tr>
        <th>EXCEL SHEET NAME</th>
    </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <th>...sheetsnames</th>
        </tr>   
  </table>
                
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be like this

```
<%try
{
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(NAME));
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
    Iterator<Sheet> sheets = workbook.sheetIterator();
%><table border=1 align=center style="text-align:center">
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>EXCEL SHEET NAME</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%while(sheets.next())
    {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=sheets.next().getSheetName()%></td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
       </tbody>
    </table><br>
<%}
catch(Exception e){
    out.print(e.getMessage());%><br><%
}
finally{
    st.close();
    con.close();
}
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.. but is there not a way to do this only inside my jsp page, without changing more things in my java code?

Comment: https://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/724201/JSP-Creating-Dynamic-Tables.htm


maybe this link can help you

Comment: The link just showed how to create dynamic tables on jsp.. but what i want is to take my System.out.println and insert it on my jsp table page.